# minimum bits for a 2s complement of a number

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I came across the question to find out 2's complement of -32 .
how to determine in minimum no of bits  how -32 is represented in 2's complements.
Is it 1100000 or 100000

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to compute 2's complement is adding 1 to its 1's complement. 
Using 7 bits (min for 32) 32 is `0100000`, so -32 is `1011111` using 1's complement. With 2's complement, you add 1 so it becomes `1100000`.